# Struggling to understand why magnetism travels through a vacuum

Tags: forces, magnetic-fields, vacuum

I have recently been pondering over my sandwich how can a magnet attract a metal, furthermore, how can it attract same in a vacuum, such as space. Is there an explanation of how the force works?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100621/discussion-on-question-by-bartley-struggling-to-understand-why-magnetism-travels).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is an explanation. The physics of magnetism has been studied for several centuries, and there is now a very detailed and comprehensive set of theoretical models that explain the effects of magnetism very precisely.

The short explanation is that there are certain forces that seem fundamental to nature, one of which is called the electromagnetic force (gravity is another that you will be familiar with). These forces do not need any medium, such as air, to convey them.

The electromagnetic force is responsible for most of the properties of everyday objects, since it is the biggest factor that determines how atoms and molecules bind together. Crudely speaking, all matter produces magnetic effects at a microscopic level, but usually the effects are in random directions and cancel out. With some materials there is a systematic alignment of the microscopic magnetic effects, which makes them add-up to a large overall effect of the sort that we experience when we play with magnets.

Certain particles, such as electrons, have a fundamental property we call 'electric charge'. We say it is fundamental because we can't break it down and explain it in terms of other properties. The charge comes in two types, which we call positive and negative. Charges of the same type repel each other, while different charges attract each other. Magnetism is a manifestation of this force of attraction and repulsion between charges.

Modern theories of physics model the force as being mediated by go-between particles called photons, but the theories are very mathematical, and it is hard to get an intuitive feel for them without confronting a lot of maths.

Comment: Thanks Marco fro breaking it down into very understandable terminology. Yet, as all good explanations do, I have leading questions, such as is the magnetic force between two large masses such as planets and stars the  sum of the micro magnetism forces between  all tiny masses they  comprise? If the transfer of magnetism as such can be represented by photons travelling between the charged particles why do you think they travel such large distances to convey the magnetism of large masses such as planets and stars?

Comment: ... I'm deeply curious to learn and discuss more around this subject, would you have a good source to connect me to?

Comment: but maybe I'm confusing magnetism for gravity...

Comment: You’re confusing the two. Any magnetic force between the Earth and Sun is insignificant. Only gravity matters for the Solar System. To understand the Solar System to good accuracy, you need nothing more than Newtonian mechanics and Newton’s inverse-square law of gravity. General Relativity plays only a tiny role, and gravitons, if they exist, no measurable role at all.

Comment: The force of gravity between the Earth and Sun is really due to a gravitational force between every particle in the Earth and every particle in the Sun. All these forces add up to give a net force that, almost by accident, happens to depend only only the distance between the centers of the two bodies, even though almost none of the pairs of particles are separated by that distance.

Answer (score -2):

The force of magnetism is actually electricity viewed from through the lens of Special Relativity. While mathematics there gets complicated, it's worth keeping in mind that electricity and magnetism are the same things viewed from a different viewpoint. Now as far as how magnetism works, it is a field mediated force. In a vacuum, the magnet can still attract another magnet because they interact through the electromagnetic field. While most forces require contact or interaction, the electromagnetic force allows things to be attracted from a distance because they interact with this "field", which in turn tells the other magnet how to move. The mathematics here is complicated (see Maxwell's Equations, EM Induction, and Magnetic Fields), but in general, magnets attract things by creating fields around themselves that tell other magnets how to move.

Comment: Magnetism is not electricity viewed through special relativity.  Magnetism and electricity are not the same things viewed from different viewpoints.  There are certain magnetic fields that can be understood as boosted electric fields, but a general magnetic field cannot.  Contact forces are electromagnetic; the objects involved never really touch.